# Missing group in Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :  `"xvvv   123y"`

I wanted to test the `replace` command

So I created :

`"xvvv   123y".match(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/)`

result :

`["vvv   123", "vvv", "123"]` //let's remember this array.

All Ok.

- Now say I want to replace the matching text to group  `$1` ==>

  `"xvvv   123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/,'$1')`

  result : `"xvvvy"` Ok.
- Now say I want to replace the matching text to group  `$2` ==>

  `"xvvv   123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/,'$2')`

  result : `"x123y"` Ok.
- Now say I want to replace the matching text to group  `$0`  ==>

  ```
                  ["vvv   123", "vvv", "123"]
                         ^ 
                         |
  I mean to -------------
  ```

  `"xvvv   123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/,'$0')`

  result : `"x$0y"`  **OOPSS ?**

Why it wont allow me replace the matching text to the first indexe group ?

## edit

And why it returns the first element if **I cant access it** ?

Comment: What's your expected result? (If it's "xvvv 123y", then use **`$&`** instead of `$0`)

Comment: The first item in the array returned by `.match` (when not using `/g`) is the whole match, **not** a match group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element in the return value of `match` is the string which represents the full match. This value is accessible through `$&`:

```
"xvvv 123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/, '$&');
// Result: ""xvvv 123y"
```

Comment: `$&` this is what i needed. where is the documentation on this token and why they didnt do `$0` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace As for reason, probably because Perl changes the definition.

Comment: If i had open a function like : `.replace(/.../, function (...){});` The params would have been : `($& , $1,$2)` ???

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes (although the first one is not a valid argument name, but you got the point).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Check the MDN link I posted, it's described in there in details.

Comment: @RobW can you please goto http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19941/room-for-royi-namir-and-rob-w

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new matching group :

```
"xvvv 123y".replace(/((v+).+?([0-9]+))/,'$1')
```

As an alternative, you can also use a replacer function

```
"xvvv 123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/,function(){
    return arguments[0];
});
```

Or use Rob's answer method

```
"xvvv 123y".replace(/(v+).+?([0-9]+)/, '$&');
```